# Difference btw MVEL.eval and MVEL.executeExpression

Tags: java, mvel

I'm using a `MVEL` script (string expression) in my java application and trying to decide between running the script with `MVEL. eval(script, container)` or with  `MVEL.executeExpression(compiledScript, container)`.

To be honest, I don't understand the difference between the 2 (they both compile and run fine). I'm using a unit test to investigate the execution time of the 2 options and from what I've noticed so far, the `MVEL.executeExpression` works faster than the `MVEL.eval`.

What are the core difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

by reading the java doc, one is compile + execution, another is execution